# Tune input features using backprop in keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, backpropagation

I am trying to implement discriminant condition codes in Keras as proposed in

> Xue, Shaofei, et al., "Fast adaptation of deep neural network based
>   on discriminant codes for speech recognition."

The main idea is you encode each condition as an input parameter and let the network learn dependency between the condition and the feature-label mapping. On a new dataset instead of adapting the entire network you just tune these weights using backprop. For example say my network looks like this

```
          X ---->|----|
                 |DNN |----> Y
          Z --- >|----|
```

`X`: features `Y`: labels `Z`:condition codes

Now given a pretrained DNN, and `X'`,`Y'` on a new dataset I am trying to estimate the `Z'` using backprop that will minimize prediction error on `Y'`. The math seems straightforward except I am not sure how to implement this in keras without having access to the backprop itself.

For instance, can I add an Input() layer with trainable=True  with all other layers set to trainable= False. Can backprop in keras update more than just layer weights? Or is there a way to hack keras layers to do this?

Any suggestions welcome.
thanks

Comment: so when you have `X', Y'` and a pre-trained model (i.e. `DNN` in your figure), are you going to freeze everything and train only for `Z`?

Comment: Yes all other weights are frozen, I only want to estimate the Z' that will minimize error on Y' given X'. Some papers will sometimes update the weights that connect Z' to the rest of the network, but nothing else is updated.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out how to do this (exactly) in Keras by looking at `fchollet`'s post [here](https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html)

Using the keras backend I was able to compute the gradient of my loss w.r.t to `Z` directly and used it to drive the update.

Code below:

```
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

model.summary() #Pretrained model
loss = K.categorical_crossentropy(Y, Y_out)
grads = K.gradients(loss, Z)
grads /= (K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(grads)))+ 1e-5)

iterate = K.function([X,Z],[loss,grads])

step = 0.1

Z_adapt = Z_in.copy()

for i in range(100):
     loss_val, grads_val = iterate([X_in,Z_adapt])
     Z_adapt -= grads_val[0] * step
     print "iter:",i,np.mean(loss_value)

print "Before:"
print model.evaluate([X_in, Z_in],Y_out)


print "After:"
print model.evaluate([X_in, Z_adapt],Y_out)
```

`X,Y,Z` are nodes in the model graph. `Z_in` is an initial value for `Z'`. I set it to an average value from the train set. `Z_adapt` is after 100 iterations of gradient descent and should give you a better result.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the size of `Z` is `m x n`. Then you can first define an input layer of size `m * n x 1`. The input will be an `m * n x 1` vector of ones. You can define a dense layer containing `m * n` neurons and set `trainable = True` for it. The response of this layer will give you a flattened version of `Z`. Reshape it appropriately and give it as input to the rest of the network that can be appended ahead of this.

Keep in mind that if the size of `Z` is too large, then network may not be able to learn a dense layer of that many neurons. In that case, maybe you need to put additional constraints or look into convolutional layers. However, convolutional layers will put some constraints on `Z`.

Comment: `Z` is typically going to be a 1-hot vector of size `k` encoding conditions. So if I understand your suggestion correctly I should add a dense layer on top with `k^2 + k` parameters that will transform a vector of ones (I) to the desired `Z`. Going by that logic I was wondering if it might make sense to use only a single 1 as input instead and transform it to `Z` using linear weights. Atleast the dense layer weights are directly interpretable in that case, also it might lead to smaller number of excess parameters.

Comment: I assume you plan to use a dense layer of `k` neurons (correct me if wrong). Now, if you have one hot encoding, then I would suggest that convert those into integers (e.g. `[0 0 1 0 0]` to `2`). Now you have a single scalar to learn. You can use two dense layers because I doubt if a single dense layer containing one neuron will be able to get a good approximation for `z`. You can use vector of say 10 ones as input, then say 10 (or 100, depending on your data amount) hidden neuron layer and then one neuron output layer, that is basically `Z`. Convert this to one-hot encoding again.

Comment: I did not get your point about using a single 1 as input and transforming it to `Z`. If you are thinking about a single 1 as input and then k-neuron layer to produce one-hot encoding of `Z`, I don't think it would work. I mentioned the strategy of converting it to scalars above, here is one more. Have k-neurons but threshold their activation to produce a one-hot vector (activn >= 0.5 or <0.5). Give that as input. Even this may be tough to learn for neural network. You may need to add some auxillary (intermediate) loss to control learning of `Z`. However, you should have multiple ones in input.

Comment: I think I found the exact solution for now (see my answer). I would like to try your answer later and update though. I would be interested to see what input representation makes sense in that case.Thanks.

Comment: I think your method will be better as it is directly updating `Z`.