# Find input that maximises output of a neural network using Keras and TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have used Keras and TensorFlow to classify the [Fashion MNIST](https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist) following [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification) .

It uses the [AdamOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer) to find the value for model parameters that minimize the loss function of the network. The input for the network is a 2-D tensor with shape [28, 28], and output is a 1-D tensor with shape [10] which is the result of a softmax function.

Once the network has been trained, I want to use the optimizer for another task: find an input that maximizes one of the elements of the output tensor. How can this be done? Is it possible to do so using Keras or one have to use a lower level API?

Since the input is not unique for a given output, it would be even better if we could impose some constraints on the values the input can take.

The trained model has the following format

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

Answer (score 8):

I feel you would want to backprop with respect to the input freezing all the weights to your model. What you could do is:

1. Add a dense layer after the input layer with the same dimensions as input and set it as trainable
2. Freeze all the other layers of your model. (except the one you added)
3. As an input, feed an identity matrix and train your model based on whatever output you desire.

[This](https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html) article and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353851/tune-input-features-using-backprop-in-keras) post might be able to help you if you want to backprop based on the input instead. It's a bit like what you are aiming for but you can get the intuition.

Comment: The input would have to be just a single scalar, `1.`, right? So that only one parameter per neuron is trained, i.e. the input value at that "position".

Comment: Hi, @Anakhand, sorry for the late reply. I am not sure if I understand your question in the context. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Say have an input space of $n$ dimensions, and let it be flat (only one axis) for simplicity. Then we want to find $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that maximizes the model's output. By adding a "fake" fully-connected linear layer (with no activation) without biases, that takes an input of dimension 1, a single scalar of value `1.`, the layer will have exactly n parameters, and the output of each neuron will simply be the value of its single parameter. I've made a diagram to il·lustrate it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mixxLWHWkcfx16NJ-T_Hb-egGaIk_YJO) (only the first layer, ignore the rest).

Comment: Hey @Anakhand, thanks for your explanation. It's much clearer now. The identity matrix would perform the exact same function in fact. Since in every row there will a single scalar value of 1 interacting with exactly one weight parameter, it would essentially be doing the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

It would be very similar to the way that filters of a Convolutional Network is visualized: we would do **gradient ascent** optimization in **input space** to **maximize the response** of a particular filter.

Here is how to do it: after training is finished, first we need to specify the output and define a loss function that we want to maximize:

```
from keras import backend as K

output_class = 0 # the index of the output class we want to maximize
output = model.layers[-1].output
loss = K.mean(output[:,output_class]) # get the average activation of our desired class over the batch
```

Next, we need to take the gradient of the loss we have defined above with respect to the input layer:

```
grads = K.gradients(loss, model.input)[0] # the output of `gradients` is a list, just take the first (and only) element

grads = K.l2_normalize(grads) # normalize the gradients to help having an smooth optimization process
```

Next, we need to define a backend function that takes the initial input image and gives the values of loss and gradients as outputs, so that we can use it in the next step to implement the optimization process:

```
func = K.function([model.input], [loss, grads])
```

Finally, we implement the gradient ascent optimization process:

```
import numpy as np

input_img = np.random.random((1, 28, 28)) # define an initial random image

lr = 1.  # learning rate used for gradient updates
max_iter = 50  # number of gradient updates iterations
for i in range(max_iter):
    loss_val, grads_val = func([input_img])
    input_img += grads_val * lr  # update the image based on gradients
```

Note that, after this process is finished, to display the image you may need to make sure that all the values in the image are in the range [0, 255] (or [0,1]).

Comment: Is there a way to use the already implemented optimizers instead of having to code gradient ascent "from scratch", which can be prone to e.g. numerical instability?

Answer (score 2):

After the hints Saket Kumar Singh gave in his answer, I wrote the following that seems to solve the question.

I create two custom layers. Maybe Keras offers already some classes that are equivalent to them.

The first on is a trainable input:

```
class MyInputLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(MyInputLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                      shape=self.output_dim,
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(MyInputLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        return self.kernel

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return self.output_dim
```

The second one gets the probability of the label of interest:

```
class MySelectionLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, position, **kwargs):
        self.position = position
        self.output_dim = 1
        super(MySelectionLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(MySelectionLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        mask = np.array([False]*x.shape[-1])
        mask[self.position] = True
        return tf.boolean_mask(x, mask,axis=1)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return self.output_dim
```

I used them in this way:

```
# Build the model
layer_flatten =  keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28))
layerDense1 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu)
layerDense2 = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
model = keras.Sequential([
    layer_flatten,
    layerDense1,
    layerDense2
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
# ...

# Freeze the model
layerDense1.trainable = False
layerDense2.trainable = False

# Build another model
class_index = 7

layerInput =  MyInputLayer((1,784))
layerSelection = MySelectionLayer(class_index)

model_extended = keras.Sequential([
    layerInput,
    layerDense1,
    layerDense2,
    layerSelection
])

# Compile it
model_extended.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss='mean_absolute_error')

# Train it
dummyInput = np.ones((1,1))
target = np.ones((1,1))
model_extended.fit(dummyInput, target,epochs=300)

# Retrieve the weights of layerInput
layerInput.get_weights()[0]
```

Comment: I just tried to implement to see how the input changes after training, but it did not work. Could please you also implement on your end and post the before and after result?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Maybe a solution would be to feed all your data to the network and for each sample save the `output_layer` after `softmax`.

This way, for *3 classes*, where you want to find the best input for *class 1*, you are looking for outputs where the first component is high. For example: `[1 0 0]`

Indeed the output means the probability, or the confidence of the network, for the sample being one of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Funny coincident I was just working on the same "problem". I'm interested in the direction of adversarial training etc. What I did was to insert a `LocallyConnected2D` Layer after the input and then train with data which is all one and has as targets the class of interest.

As model I use

```
batch_size = 64
num_classes = 10
epochs = 20
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)


inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inp)
pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))(conv1)
drop1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.20)(pool1)
flat  = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(drop1)
fc1   = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(flat)
norm1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(fc1)
dropfc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25)(norm1)
out   = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(dropfc1)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = inp , outputs = out)

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

after training I insert the new layer

```
def insert_intermediate_layer_in_keras(model,position, before_layer_id):
    layers = [l for l in model.layers]

    if(before_layer_id==0) :
        x = new_layer
    else:
        x = layers[0].output
    for i in range(1, len(layers)):
        if i == before_layer_id:
            x = new_layer(x)
            x = layers[i](x)

        else:
            x = layers[i](x)

    new_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=layers[0].input, outputs=x)
    return new_model

def fix_model(model):
    for l in model.layers:
        l.trainable=False


fix_model(model)    
new_layer = tf.keras.layers.LocallyConnected2D(1, kernel_size=(1, 1),
                                               activation='linear',
                                               kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                                                use_bias=False)
new_model = insert_intermediate_layer_in_keras(model,new_layer,1)
new_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and finally rerun training with my fake data.

```
X_fake = np.ones((60000,28,28,1))
print(Y_test.shape)
y_fake = np.ones((60000))
Y_fake = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_fake, num_classes)
new_model.fit(X_fake, Y_fake, epochs=100)
weights = new_layer.get_weights()[0]

imshow(weights.reshape(28,28))
plt.show()
```

Results are not yet satisfying but I'm confident of the approach and guess I need to play around with the optimiser.