# Find Input that maximizes class output score in tensorflow JS

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, tensorflow.js

I have a trained CNN network for the MNIST dataset in tensorflow JS. I am trying to tune the input so that one of the output scores is maximized. I know how to do this in python using keras like so:

```
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np


class_num = 0 
output = model.layers[-1].output
loss = K.mean(output[:,class_num]) 

grads = K.gradients(loss, model.input)[0] 
grads = K.l2_normalize(grads)

func = K.function([model.input], [loss, grads])


input = np.random.random((1, 28, 28)) 

for i in range(10):
    loss_val, grads_val = func([input])
    input_img += grads_val
```

The problem is I don't know how to do the same in tensorflow JS. Can someone help in a similar implementation for tensorflow JS? I am unable to get working loss and gradient functions. Many Thanks!

Comment: When you say you're trying to tune the input do you mean the weights? Guessing you don't mean you are changing the images themselves?

Comment: I want to tune the images themselves using gradient ascent. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52678215/find-input-that-maximises-output-of-a-neural-network-using-keras-and-tensorflow . I want to do something similar in tensorflow JS. I want to maximize the output for a particular class

Comment: Interesting problem but can't say I am familiar enough with it to help.